# Google analytic for multiple pages having the same base URL

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api

The current method/code which I use for tracking my pages displays just one details in Google search.

I was wondering if there is any special method to display the results in the following manner? {Multiple links under one common name}

[image]

How can I do that? Is it possible?or this happens automatically depending upon the visits by the audience?

I searched in many blogs/tutorials but was unable to find an answer.

Comment: google analytics is for tracking visitor behavior on your site.  It doesn't really have anything to do w/ what you see on google's search results page, though I suppose it's *possible* google may internally take advantage of your GA imp...but it's nothing you would change or set within GA..but you already got an answer of where to affect it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can do that. You should use Google Webmaster Tools: https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/

Just register to google, add your domain to webmaster tools. Login and go to Configuration/Sitelinks.

"Sitelinks are automatically generated links that may appear under your site's search results.  If you don't want a page to appear as a sitelink, you can demote it. Only site owners and users with full permissions can demote sitelinks."

Comment: Thanks. I used official **Google Analytics**. There was no such option there.

Comment: I'm glad I could help you. I suggest you to use Webmaster tools for all your websites. This tool help you with SEO and also Page errors, statistics and many more.

Comment: Also, I had a doubt. Should I add the site profile to Google Analytics as well? I mean, from where else could I get the tracking code as Webmaster Tools doesn't provide a tracking ID (or I'm unable to find it there)

Comment: When you add a website on Webmaster Tools you must confirm it's yours by passing this steps: 1. Download this HTML verification file. [googledsadds311617a.html]

2. Upload the file to http://website.com/

3. Confirm successful upload by visiting http://website.com/googledc19cdasdasd7a.html in your browser.

4. Click Verify below.

To stay verified, don't remove the HTML file, even after verification succeeds.

Comment: if you want detailed traffic statistics you should add your website to Google Analytics, there should be a tracking code, on Google Webmaster Tools isn't any tracking code.